# How do I find a good Texas-based dog charity?

Tags: dogs, shelter

I'd like to make a several hundred dollar donation to a dog charity based in Texas. My goal is to make the money go as far as possible in helping abandoned or rescued dogs find new and hopefully permanent homes.

Given the above, what are the main criteria I should consider in looking for a charity to donate to? And are there any gold-standard organizations local to Texas or that area of the states that I should consider first? (Please remember, the specific goal I have in mind is doing the most I can to help dogs get a permanent home. I definetely don't want to start a "whose charity is best" competition here, just get some good leads and figure out how to evaluate choices as evenly as I can.)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I like K-9 Angels Rescue in Houston.